# Excel: Round to 5 if between 1 and 5, otherwise, round to nearest 5

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a formula where it rounds to 5 if between 1 and 5, and otherwise, it rounds to the nearest 5.

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 5
1.5 -> 5
2 -> 5
3 -> 5
4 -> 5
5 -> 5
6 -> 5
9 -> 10
```

I'm currently using a IF(A<5,5,MROUND(A,5)) function, but I'm looking for a more elegant solution if possible and it doesn't account for 0 in my formula.

Comment: @ExcelHero Apologies, I've corrected my original post.

Comment: `=IF(AND(A1<5,A1>0),5,MROUND(A1,5))`?

Comment: @BigBen Yes, this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option:

```
=IF(AND(A1<5,A1>0),5,MROUND(A1,5))
```

Note of course that this would throw an error if `A1` contained a negative number.